# Turning a 2D dwg into a basic 3D render

Tags: modeling, import, conversion

I currently have a task to turn several 2D dwg files into basic 3D renders (building layouts); I've purchased a plugin to import 2D DWG files into Blender but am at a loss as to how to easily turn them into 3D renderings (simple enough so someone could know the layout of a floor of a building)

I've searched high and low but can't find any simple solution towards this.

Thanks,

Comment: So... You will need to manually model these or what?... Could you explain what you .dwg's actually are, cause I’m not sure I understand your problem.

Comment: @RadishoftheOpera they are building layouts per floor; they are 2D and I just wish to create a simple 3D explanation of the layout.

Comment: Yeah, you'll just have to model them.. Create a plane object([Shift]+[A] > *plane*, add loop-cuts [ctrl]+[r] where you need them, and then select all the faces that represent walls and extrude to your ceiling height. then render them by hitting [F12]

Comment: What's the name of the plugin you bought?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose you have a plan floor like this:

[image]

And you have imported your 2D geometry in Blender with your plugin:

[image]

Depending on what your plugin is capable of, you have to work a bit on the imported objects, maybe: merging, separing, removing doubles...

Than you can start extruding your 2D geometry. I suggest you to import also the elevation, if provided, in order to have quicker access on extruding values.

There are many ways in wich you can optimize the extrusion process (merge object, thickness modifier, curve extrusion,...) but all depend in which way your plugin get the 2D information out.

In my case I ony had the profile, so I had to create faces

[image]

and then extrude them:

[image]

continue till you are satisfied with your modeling by translating, extruding, adding objects.... with the help of the snaps.

Add a floor plane, a light, maybe textures and render...

[image]